# Logo for each site in site collection

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to load different logo in each site in same site collection. For now my logo tag exists in master page. Any idea ?

Comment: This can be done by creating a custom webpart which will of course switch the logo depending on the site you're on, but you'll need some kind of indicator on each site to tell which logo should be used. This can easily be done by making the logos' title contain the site's title, making it easy to compare them. Just remember to name them something unique - Forinstance SiteColl1_FrontPage, SiteColl1_AboutUs, SiteColl1_Contact.

Comment: @Ziga, I've clue to create visual web part and will loop through the image library ( where I will keep all my images ) and get the image url based on site title. But How do I set that url to this SharePoint control, ?


<SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/">
     <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage LogoImageUrl="/Style%20Library/logo.png" AlternateText="Home" ToolTip="Home" runat="server"/>
    </SharePoint:SPLinkButton>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do 2 things.

1. You can replace the SharePoint:SiteLogoImage with your own.
2. You can use Master.FindControl to find that control by doing the following

   var siteLogo = (SiteLogoImage)Page.Master.FindControl("ID of control goes here");

   siteLogo.LogoImageUrl = // Insert logo img url here

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP Dot NET then we can have more than one master page, defining logo for each one. You can call you master page at run time according to your site opened!

Please would you specify Are you using ASP DOT NET or defining master page in another lange

Comment: I've customized SharePoint 2010 master page and it's being used in many sites in same site collection.By default it displays only one logo in all sites but I want the same master page can able to display different logo based on site titie or something.